# Strategy for updating Android app (with database)

Tags: android, sqlite

Please forgive me if this question has been answered - I searched and couldn't find it.

I have an Android app that I want to upgrade, and it uses a SQLite Database. I want to update some of the application logic in the app, but there will be no updates to the database schema or contents. I basically need to keep the database exactly as-is for the user.

Do I need to do anything in onUpgrade to ensure that the database is kept, or can I leave the DB stuff alone for this update?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [related article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295423/what-happens-to-my-android-app-and-database-when-a-user-updates-through-market-p) may help you with your question.

The way that I understand it, is that you need to put your database changing code in onUpdate() if you WANT to update between versions. But since you don't intend to, and are probably keeping the database version the same, then you will most likely have no issues at all.

Comment: it is not a question of likelihood.  sqlite will retain its structure and data between versions.  between versions ONLY.  the same app with a different signing key do not access its previously occupied sandbox, regardçless of whether or not said sandbox still exists.  UPVOTED :)

Answer (score 5):

The onUpgrade() method is used incases of version change. Which means the database stored in the phone needs to be altered or dropped or deleted and a new database to be created. As your application does not have any of these requirements you can leave the DB stuff for this update.

Comment: a bit confusing, m8.  i understand (and agree with) what you mean, but the way its written, it may sound like SQLite will be recreated between versions, which is NOT the case.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading will NOT interfere with SQLite.  Changes to db structure will not be implemented unless you programmatically do so (in onUpgrade method) or you uninstall and reinstall your app.

As long as it is the SAME application that you are upgrading, your db will not be affected and your data will not be affected either.  If you change the signing key used in building your apk, your db will be recreated.

Conversely, if you change database structure at any given point, your onUpgrade method will come into play.  You will be forced to backup, drop, recreate and repopulate tables which have been changed between versions (oher tables remain untouched both in structure and in data).

NOTE: In debugging, i just uninstall and reinstall the app every time i make db changes, but in production you DONT  want to do that.